# Shell script : How to find the point of interruption and restart codes from point of interruption ?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a long shell script which runs and store results in the hive tables. The script takes very long time to complete . All results are preserved in the temporary tables . Sometimes script get killed or interrupted as it hogs lot of resources for very long time. As of now I simply copy paste the queries from the point of interruption and restart it .

I need to write a shell script that can check all temp table and the figure out at what point it got interrupted and then start from that point onwards .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a run log (through files) through shell script and keep track of queries that are already executed.

In your shell script:

```
if [ -f "query1.complete" ] 
then
   echo "Query 1 already run. Skipping"
else
   Run Query 1 
   touch query1.complete
end if

if [ -f "query2.complete" ]
then
   echo "Query 2 already run. Skipping"
else
   Run Query 2 
   touch query2.complete
end if
```

Note: Syntax of this code may not be perfect for shell.

Answer (score 0):

Since in each step I am creating a table and storing the results  so before each query I am checking if the table is present or not . I have implemented the same in following manner

```
tname=$(hive -e "use db_name ; show table LIKE 'tablename' " -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=queuename ) 
if [ -z "$tname" ]
then 
# write the next step 
else 
echo " table $tname already present hence skipping to next step "
```